# Reading elements of a countable set with Turing machine

Tags: algorithms, turing-machines, computability

I have a basic question about the behavior of a potential Turing machine.

Suppose that $S$ is a countable set of binary strings, so that we can enumerate $S$ as $(s_i)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$.

Suppose that we want to construct a Turing machine $M$ that, on any input, simply writes each element of $S$ on a tape in order $s_1, s_2, \ldots$. (I realize that $M$ will never halt.)

> But we can construct such an $M$ if and only if our particular bijection
>   $\mathbb{N} \to S$ is computable, correct?  Or is knowing that $S$ is countable somehow enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, a set $S$ is *recursively enumerable* if there is a Turing machine that enumerates it.